# Gradle + Sonar - get ClassNotFound Exception

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

My gradle configuration contains:

```
apply plugin: 'sonar'

sonar {
    server {
        url = "http://localhost:9000"
    }
    database {
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar"
        driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
        username = "username"
        password = "password"
    }
}
```

When running gradle with stacktrace I get this Exception:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task 
':sonarAnalyze'.

    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex
ecuteActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex
ecute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExec
uter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter
$1.run(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(Def
        ... 96 more

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 17.022 secs
```

What does this error mean and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ed, Did you resolve this issue? Can you share, thanks. The new documentation for Gradle 2.3 says, plugin name is "sonar" and i'm getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the old `sonar` plugin, which doesn't support recent Sonar versions. Instead, you'll have to use the new `sonar-runner` plugin. For details, see the corresponding chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Comment: Please provide all the necessary details (output of `gradle -v`, Sonar version, your exact configuration, exact error message and stack trace, etc.), ideally over at http://forums.gradle.org.